# How to access an element inside a div in jQuery?

Tags: html, jquery

here's my html code :

```
    <section>
        <div class="article">
            
            <p>
                things aren't thing anymore they basically copy of originally thing created bu someone no one know as now we can calll them copy's
            </p>
        </div>
    </section>
    <br>    
    <section>
        <div class="article">

            <p>
                things aren't thing anymore they basically copy of originally thing created bu someone no one know as now we can calll them copy's
            </p>
        </div>
    </section>  
    <br>
    <section>
        <div class="article">

            <p>
                things aren't thing anymore they basically copy of originally thing created bu someone no one know as now we can calll them copy's
            </p>
        </div>
    </section>
```

that my jquery code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".article").append('<span class="close" style="top:0px;background:#000;color:#fff;padding:10px;cursor:pointer;">X</span>');

        $(".close").click(function(){
            $(this).parents(".article > p").hide();
        

    });

});
```

I want to hide `<p>` when the user click on span , how can i have access to `<p>` only by jquery instead of typing `<span>X</span>` 3 times in html ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `find()`.

`parents()` uses `filter()` under the hood to check whether the node matches the selector. Here the `p` node matches `.article > p`, but its not one of the parents of `.close`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".article").append('<span class="close" style="top:0px;background:#000;color:#fff;padding:10px;cursor:pointer;">X</span>');

  $(".close").click(function() {
    $(this).parents(".article").find('p').hide();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <div class="article">

    <p>
      things aren't thing anymore they basically copy of originally thing created bu someone no one know as now we can calll them copy's
    </p>
  </div>
</section>
<br>
<section>
  <div class="article">

    <p>
      things aren't thing anymore they basically copy of originally thing created bu someone no one know as now we can calll them copy's
    </p>
  </div>
</section>
<br>
<section>
  <div class="article">

    <p>
      things aren't thing anymore they basically copy of originally thing created bu someone no one know as now we can calll them copy's
    </p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is you can't use `parents()` to look up to a parent  and have that same selector look inside the parent

Some alternatives are use `find()` or `siblings()`:

```
// go up to the parent then find the descendents inside that parent
$(this).parents(".article").find("p").hide();
// OR the span is a sibling of the `<p>` and can target them directly
$(this).siblings("p").hide()// or toggle() if want to show again on alternate clicks
```